# Angular ng-repeat not working with my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have three jsFiddles that demonstrate my problem: 1)[Not working](http://jsfiddle.net/boydjohnson/kzgzr291/) 2)[Shows the array](http://jsfiddle.net/boydjohnson/0zLn3dwz/3/) 3)[Working with small array](http://jsfiddle.net/91byppwt/)

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <div ng-repeat="date in [0,1,2,3]" ng-bind="date" class="day"></div>
</div>
```

Part of my controller:

```
$scope.month_calendar = function (num) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        arr.push($scope.year_calendar.slice(i * 35, (i + 1) * 35));
$scope.monthly_calendar = $scope.month_calendar($scope.month);
```

I am trying to make a calendar with ng-repeat where the dates are repeated.  When I use a short little arbitrary array it works.  When I use the monthly_calendar array it doesn't work, but I can also just print out the monthly_calendar array and it changes when the month changes.  Does anyone know why my array won't work in ng-repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS [does not allow duplicates](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2013/06/15/duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed-in-angularjs/) in `ng-repeat` directive. To fix that use the following:

```
... ng-repeat="date in monthly_calendar track by $index" ...
```

- **DEMO 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/kzgzr291/5/
- **DEMO 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/0zLn3dwz/4/